# Problems with postgres and Unicorn server

Tags: postgresql, server, unicorn

When I try running Unicorn after setting up postgres (works perfectly with Trinidad and Thin) I get the following error.

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: 
Symbol not found: _rb_thread_select 
Referenced from:/Users/pls/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0@coinino/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.2.0/do_postgres-0.10.14/do_postgres/do_postgres.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace
```

Datamapper connects to the database normally inside a model.rb which then is required in app.rb.

What is wrong and how do I fix it?

**Edit: Looks like this is a bug in Ruby 2.2.0.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is a bug in Ruby 2.2.0. Going to Ruby 2.1.5 gets things going without trouble.

Answer (score 5):

A call used by old versions of the `pg` gem has been removed in Ruby 2.2. More recent versions of the gem no longer use this call; I know the latest version (0.18.1) doesn't, but I don't know when that change was made. You can update the `pg` gem by running the following command:

```
bundle update pg
```

As long as you're doing this, you may want to run just a plain `bundle update` to update all of your project's gems to the most recent versions—who knows what else might be incompatible with Ruby 2.2?

As always when updating dependencies, test that the update doesn't introduce any new bugs before you deploy the new version to production. I doubt `pg` will cause any problems, but other gems might.