# App stopped working after switching to Postgres

Tags: sqlite, postgresql, heroku, sinatra, datamapper

My Sinatra app was working fine on a local install with sqlite. When moved to Heroku, I had weird errors, so I switched to Postgres in my local app, too, and I am receiving these errors:

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _rb_thread_select
  Referenced from: /Users/Emanuele/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.2.0-static/do_postgres-0.10.14/do_postgres/do_postgres.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace

dyld: Symbol not found: _rb_thread_select
  Referenced from: /Users/Emanuele/.rbenv/versions/2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-14/2.2.0-static/do_postgres-0.10.14/do_postgres/do_postgres.bundle
  Expected in: flat namespace
```

The same happens when loading the model in irb.

Here is my model file:

```
require 'data_mapper'
require 'dm-types'
require 'dm-validations'
require 'dm-postgres-adapter'
require 'bcrypt'

# Setup DataMapper with a database URL. Will use ENV['DATABASE_URL'] on Heroku.
DataMapper.setup(:default, 'postgres://localhost/myapp')

# Let's define the model
class User
  include DataMapper::Resource
  include BCrypt

  property :id, Serial, :key => true
  property :email, String, :length => 5..70, :unique => true, :required => true, :format => :email_address
  property :password, BCryptHash
  property :account_sid, String, :length => 34
  property :auth_token, String, :length => 32
  property :app_sid, String, :length => 34

  def authenticate(attempted_password)
    if self.password == attempted_password
      true
    else
      false
    end
  end

end

# Finalize the DataMapper model.
DataMapper.finalize

# Tell DataMapper to update the database according to the definitions above.
DataMapper.auto_upgrade!
```

When I switch back to sqlite3 the app starts working again. I can't manage to hunt down the error. Searching online has not yield any result.

Does anyone have any idea about what's going on and how I can fix this and publish my app on Heroku?

If you need more info, please ask.

Thanks!

Comment: Yep, I'm on a Mac, but it looks like the issue was Ruby 2.2.0. Switching back to 2.1.5 solved the issue. Go figure.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like switching back to Ruby 2.1.5 from 2.2.0 solved the issue both locally and on Heroku. Go figure what was going wrong.

If more experienced devs want to track down the bug and need me to provide some info, please ask.

Answer (score 1):

Old versions of the `pg` gem aren't compatible with Ruby 2.2; you'll want to update to the latest version. See [my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27995428/41222) for more details, including updating instructions.

Comment: I'm sorry Brent, but I had already updated the gems. In fact I tried again and checked that I am `Using pg 0.18.1`, but the errors persist. Again, switching back to 2.1.5. If you have further details, please provide them. I would really like to use 2.2.0 as I've read about performance improvements.

Comment: As a data point, I also had this problem (I had pg gem 0.14.0, and had newly upgraded to Ruby 2.2), and updating the pg gem to 0.18.1 fixed it for me.